# Unable to retrieve data stored in IndexedDB by Date using Blazor Server application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, indexeddb

This is my first Blazor Server application and before implementing a server-side database I was storing data in the browser's IndexedDB data store while prototyping my application. I am using the [Blazor.IndexedDB](https://github.com/wtulloch/Blazor.IndexedDB) library and .NET Core 5.0.

Following the Blazor.IndexDB ReadMe I've set up the schema in the Startup.cs ConfigureServices function, setting up two indexes, one for "date" and one for "category".

```
services.AddIndexedDB(dbStore =>
        {
            dbStore.DbName = "WordsDB"; //example name
            dbStore.Version = 1;

            dbStore.Stores.Add(new StoreSchema
            {
                Name = "Written",
                PrimaryKey = new IndexSpec { Name = "Id", KeyPath = "Id", Auto = true },
                Indexes = new List<IndexSpec>
                {
                    new IndexSpec{Name="date", KeyPath = "date", Auto = false, Unique = false},
                    new IndexSpec{Name="category", KeyPath = "category", Auto = false}
                }
            });
            
        });
```

After entering some data using the AddWords.razor page I want to display data entered on the current day on the same page so I set up a new query using StoreIndexQuery with some predefined parameters (selected index specified as "date"; search string as today's date).

```
protected List<Words> todaysWords { get; set; } = new List<Words>();

protected string selectedIndex { get; set; } = "date";
protected string searchString { get; set; } = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00";

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    SearchForTodaysWords();
}

protected async void SearchForTodaysWords()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedIndex))
    {
        return;
    }

    var indexSearch = new StoreIndexQuery<string>
    {
        Storename = DbManager.Stores[0].Name,
        IndexName = selectedIndex,
        QueryValue = searchString
    };

    var db = await DbManager.GetAllRecordsByIndex<string, Words>(indexSearch);
    
    if (db is null)
    {
        return;
    }

    todaysWords.AddRange(db);
}
```

But if I query with the date of "2021-08-30T00:00:00" I get zero records returned (I have tried both "date" and "Date" as my index name).

The data is stored in IndexedDB formatted like this:

[image: IndexedDB Data]

The initial starting point was the Blazor Server starting application).

Any additional questions please let me know. Thanks in advance.